# Rearrangement Inequality- $\sum_{c y c} \frac{a^{2}+b c}{b+c} \geq a+b+c$

Tags: inequality, rearrangement-inequality

$$\sum_{c y c} \frac{a^{2}+b c}{b+c} \geq a+b+c$$

I'm confused about how to solve this. can someone give me a few hints?
I'm stuck thing what even $\sum_{c y c}$ means!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Karan Lokchandani I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: It's true for all $(b+c)(c+a)(a+b) \geqslant 0.$

Comment: @tthnew It means $(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)>0,$ otherwise it's wrong for $a+b=0.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just Power-Mean Inequality.
By Inequality of AM and HM,
$$ \sum_{cyc}{a^2+bc\over b+c} \geq \sum_{cyc}{a} \Rightarrow \sum_{cyc}{\left({a^2+bc\over b}+{a^2+bc\over c}\right)} \geq 4\sum_{cyc}{a} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \sum_{cyc}{\left( {a^2\over b}+{b^2\over a} \right)} \geq 2\sum_{cyc}{a} $$
Notice that
$$ {a^2\over b}+ b\ge 2a $$ and $$ {b^2\over a}+a\ge 2b $$ And by $4$ other similar inequalities summing up, we meet our desire.

Comment: I think, your solution is wrong. Even for positive variables the first step does not give a proof because you proved weaker inequality.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sum_{cyc} \frac{a^2 + bc}{b+ c} = \frac{a^2 + bc}{b + c} + \frac{b^2 + ca }{c + a} + \frac{c^2 + ab}{a + b}$$
Is it clear now?